# How to get the finest possible precision in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers, precision

I'm trying to determine the smallest possible **non-negative**, **non-zero** value available in a JavaScript number for addition and subtraction. If necessary then the smallest possible number for addition and subtraction per a given value (i.e. if the "smallest value" differs between numbers at a given range I'd like to find the smallest value for a given number or range of numbers, or the next number greater or smaller than a given number would also work.)

As an example to underline why I'm looking for this, please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7od5vLy/1/) or the code below.  It simply scales a rectangle by area, given both the starting width/height and ending width/height the values should be in whole numbers.  It works as outlined below for the given example however I'm fairly sure the fudge-factor of `0.000000000000002` won't scale to any possible set of values.  I understand the overwhelming majority of solutions in the floating point range of possible values will not be whole numbers and that many will likely even extend beyond the JavaScript number's level of precision or simply be unable to be represented in it, however given the check below for greater than or less than based on ration and/or area I have a high degree of confidence that if I can find the smallest possible value which the result can be offset I can at least hit the number most computationally accurate for a given input, which would be the objective here.

```
console.clear();
var w = 3;
var h = 5;
var a = w * h;
var r = w / h;
console.log(w, h, a, r);
var t = 240;
var w2 = Math.sqrt(t);
var h2 = w2;
w2 = w2 * r / Math.sqrt(r);
h2 = h2 / r * Math.sqrt(r);
var r2 = w2 / h2;
var m = 10;
var a2 = w2 * h2;
console.log(w2, h2, a2, r2);
while ((r2 > r) && (m > 0)) {
    h2 += 0.000000000000002;
    r2 = w2 / h2;
    m--;
}
m = 10;
while ((r2 < r) && (m > 0)) {
    h2 -= 0.000000000000002;
    r2 = w2 / h2;
    m--;
}
var a2 = w2 * h2;
console.log(w2, h2, a2, r2);
```

Output:

```
Console was cleared
3 5 15 0.6
12 20.000000000000004 240.00000000000006 0.5999999999999999
12 20 240 0.6
```

Comment: https://github.com/scijs/nextafter ?

Comment: Thanks, I'm avoiding that one due to the dependency to another library but the keyword lead me to https://gist.github.com/Yaffle/4654250 so if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest possible number can be interpreted in several ways. For the sake of usefulness to others I will post information about all three interpretations, although I believe you are looking for the first one:

If you mean in terms of precision - the smallest possible number closest to zero:

```
Number.MIN_VALUE
```

would give you: `5e-324`

If instead you mean the smallest possible floating point number, which would include negative numbers, then you'd be looking for:

```
- Number.MAX_VALUE
```

Note the minus sign there. That would give you: `-1.7976931348623157e+308`.

And the third interpretation is the difference between 1 and the smallest floating point number greater than 1, also known as the Machine Epsilon, in which case you can use:

```
Number.EPSILON
```

Which would give you: `-2.220446049250313e-16`.

As a final note, the examples may be inaccurate if you are running on a CPU that supports different floating point storage scheme, like a 32bit CPU for example.

Comment: @CoryG An year and a half late, but hopefully useful to others, as it was useful to me.